# Get url from FQDN using python

Tags: python, url, fqdn

I have a list of FQDNs and would need to get the url it points to using python. Any pointers about how I could achieve this?

Added http:// as suggested by @tetech it is giving this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='edge-mqtt-shv-01-any2.facebook.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9b534ad7f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)
```

Used this code:

```
import requests
requests.get("http://edge-mqtt-shv-01-any2.facebook.com")
```

Comment: The FQDN is part of the URL. So what are you trying to do ? What did you already try ?

Comment: Ok, I am trying to crawl the website whose fqdn I have.

Comment: The fqdn is something like this: edge-mqtt-shv-01-any2.facebook.com

Comment: Add `http://` to the start

Comment: update question with error

Comment: Then there's no service running on port 80.  Add `https://` instead.  I somehow think this isn't being done as part of a business IT environment.

Comment: " I somehow think this isn't being done as part of a business IT environment" - means?

Comment: `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))`
with https

Comment: Then the server refused your request.  Probably because you look like a crawler and it doesn't want to be crawled.

Comment: That means it's off topic here. There are already votes in progress to migrate it over to [so], where it fits better. That shouldn't take long.